# Make an outline out of filled shape with Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm not sure the title really reflects what I want to do so I will just show you what I want:

[image]

From the shape on left I want to get the shape on right. I did it with an pen tool thats why it's cut out unevenly. Is there some better way to achieve this more uniformly?

Comment: Do you have access to Illustrator or a similar vector program? This is rather simple in such an app.

Comment: I have Inkscape. How do I do it? What term to google for?

Comment: I'm not sure about the exact Inkscape terms, but you'd need to vectorise the shape first (LiveTrace is what Ai calls it) and then Offset Path with a negative value.

Comment: Inkscape has a bitmap trace function. It uses the Potrace bitmap tracing engine.

To use the tracer, load or import an image, select it, and select the Path > Trace Bitmap item, or `Shift+Alt+B`

Answer (score -2):

I'd redo it all. The shapes seem simple (circles shapes with a vertex pulled to the side; real quick to do).
One for the whole umbrella outline, then three more for each cone. Play with stroke effect afterwards.